# What is the purpose of Die Priority setting in tDie?

Tags: talend

I was inspecting the tDie component and found the Die Priority setting. First, I thought it was related with the possibility of not killing the job and just notify a warning. But doing some experiments, I haven't found how to do it.

[image]

So, what is the purpose of this setting?

Comment: something which i can think of is that when you catch this exception via tLogcatcher you will be returned different priority (4,5,6...) which is based on priority (of tDie) and based on this priority you can take some futher logging action

Comment: This seems to be a misleading Spanish translation. The English label for that option is just "Priority".

Comment: Thanks @cyroxx. Now I understand the purpose. If you connect multiple tDie components with the same subjob, the priority make sense!